# Past perfect - A simple question

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

> Have you went to the party?

Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not correct, it should be:

> Have you been to the party?

or

> Did you go to the party?

Comment: Thanks man, "Have you been" is what I was searching for.